How to calculate $ \log\left(1 + \frac{i}{\sqrt{3}}\right) $, $ \log\left(i + \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)$ with branch cut $ t + i t^2 $ for $t\geq0$?
I am trying to calculate the logarithms $ \log\left(1 + \frac{i}{\sqrt{3}}\right) $ and $ \log\left(i + \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)$ with a non-standard branch cut $ t + i t^2 $ where $t\geq0$.
Instead of the typical branch cut along the negative real axis, it is asked to define the branch cut along the path $ t + i t^2 $ for $t \geq 0$, there is also imposed that $log(1) = 0$. Does this mean that $\alpha \leq arg( log(z)) <\alpha +2\pi$ where $\alpha\ne0$? I suggest this because defining $log(1)$ means the positive real line cannot be a branch cut. Feel free to correct this statement.
However, since I have no real idea on how to approach such 'exotic' branch cut I am asking the following questions:

How should I approach the calculation of $ \log\left(1 + \frac{i}{\sqrt{3}}\right) $ and $ \log\left(i + \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)$  with this branch cut?
What impact does the branch cut $t + i t^2$ have on the argument (angle) of these complex numbers?

Any help in understanding the method to calculate these logarithms with a non-standard branch cut would be greatly appreciated!

Remember that moving counterclockwise by an angle $\theta$ increases the logarithm by $i\theta$, and moving clockwise reduces the logarithm by $i\theta$. If you want to go from $1$ to $1 + \frac{i}{\sqrt{3}}$ without crossing the branch cut, do you have to go clockwise or counterclockwise? What about $\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} + i$? Drawing a picture will help.
